# Failed to Convert Parameter Value From a String to a DateTime (Visual Studio to Access Database)

Tags: string, vb.net, visual-studio, datetime, ms-access

I am trying to create a Visual Studio program that will add one new record into an Access database whenever a button is clicked. The information that is inputted into the different columns in the access database is based off of which checkboxes are checked. I am now getting this error:

[image]

I initially thought the error stemmed from a an incorrectly selected data type in my database, however I changed the types as shown below, and there are still errors.

[image]

I am lost, because I thought that I had correctly converted the dates to strings. Here is my code for reference. Thanks for the help.

```
Private Sub InputInformation(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles ImporttBUT.Click

        Dim strSql = "Insert Into [DataCollection] (
           
            [M/Y Of LOG],
            [TIME OF LOG],
            [USER],
            [STOCK NUMBER],
            [MISSED PART],
            [NOT IN EPICOR],
            [MISSED BUYOUT],
            [MISSED NON STOCK ITEM],
            [MISSED STOCK ITEM],
            [MISSED AUTOMATED],
            [MISSING PRINTS AFTER QUANTITY],
            [MISSED PRINT NOT SENT TO CHAD],
            OTHER,
            [ADDED MISSING DIMENSION],
            [FIXED DIMENSION]
            )
            Values ( @M_YLog, @TimeLog, @User, @StockNumber, @MissedPart, @NotEpicor, MissedBuyout, @MissedNonStock, @MissedStock, @MissedAutomated, @MissedPrints, @NotSent, @Other, @MissingDimension, @FixedDimension);"

        Using con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection(My.Settings.Database1ConnectionString),
            cmdSQL As New OleDbCommand(strSql, con)

            With cmdSQL.Parameters

                .Add("@M_YLog", OleDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = Me.MonthList2021.SelectedItem
                .Add("@TimeLog", OleDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss")
                .Add("@User", OleDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = UserName
                .Add("@StockNumber", OleDbType.Date, 100).Value = ""
                .Add("@MissedPart", OleDbType.VarChar, 100)
                If MissedPartCHKB.Checked Then
                    cmdSQL.Parameters("@MissedPart").Value = MissedPartCHKB.Text
                Else
                    cmdSQL.Parameters("@MissedPart").Value = "NEATOL"
                End If
                .Add("@NotEpicor", OleDbType.VarChar, 100)
                If NotInEpicorCHKB.Checked Then
                    cmdSQL.Parameters("@NotEpicor").Value = NotInEpicorCHKB.Text
                Else
                    cmdSQL.Parameters("@NotEpicor").Value = "NEATOL"
                End If
                .Add("@MissedBuyout", OleDbType.VarChar, 100)
                If MissedBuyoutCHKB.Checked = True Then
                    cmdSQL.Parameters("@MissedBuyout").Value = MissedBuyoutCHKB.Text
                Else
                    cmdSQL.Parameters("@MissedBuyout").Value = "NEATOL"
                End If
                .Add("@MissedNonStock", OleDbType.VarChar, 100)
                If NonStockCHKB.Checked = True Then
                    cmdSQL.Parameters("@MissedNonStock").Value = NonStockCHKB.Text
                Else
                    cmdSQL.Parameters("@MissedNonStock").Value = "NEATOL"
                End If
                .Add("@MissedStock", OleDbType.VarChar, 100)
                If MissedSTKItemCHKB.Checked = True Then
                    cmdSQL.Parameters("@MissedStock").Value = MissedSTKItemCHKB.Text
                Else
                    cmdSQL.Parameters("@MissedStock").Value = "NEATOL"
                End If
                .Add("@MissedAutomated", OleDbType.VarChar, 100)
                If MissedAutomatedPartCHKB.Checked = True Then
                    cmdSQL.Parameters("@MissedAutomated").Value = MissedAutomatedPartCHKB.Text
                Else
                    cmdSQL.Parameters("@MissedAutomated").Value = "NEATOL"
                End If
                .Add("@MissedPrints", OleDbType.VarChar, 100)
                If MissingPrintAfterQTYCHKB.Checked = True Then
                    cmdSQL.Parameters("@MissedPrints").Value = MissingPrintAfterQTYCHKB.Text
                Else
                    cmdSQL.Parameters("@MissedPrints").Value = "NEATOL"
                End If
                .Add("@NotSent", OleDbType.VarChar, 100)
                If MissedPrintsNOTSentChadCHKB.Checked = True Then
                    cmdSQL.Parameters("@NotSent").Value = MissedPrintsNOTSentChadCHKB.Text
                Else
                    cmdSQL.Parameters("@NotSent").Value = "NEATOL"
                End If
                .Add("@Other", OleDbType.VarChar, 100)
                If OtherCHKB.Checked = True Then
                    cmdSQL.Parameters("@Other").Value = OtherTXTB.Text
                Else
                    cmdSQL.Parameters("@Other").Value = "NEATOL"
                End If
                .Add("@MissingDimension", OleDbType.VarChar, 100)
                If AddedMissingDimCHKB.Checked = True Then
                    cmdSQL.Parameters("@MissingDimension").Value = AddedMissingDimCHKB.Text
                Else
                    cmdSQL.Parameters("@MissingDimension").Value = "NEATOL"
                End If
                .Add("@FixedDimension", OleDbType.VarChar, 100)
                If FixedDimensionCHKB.Checked = True Then
                    cmdSQL.Parameters("@FixedDimension").Value = FixedDimensionCHKB.Text
                Else
                    cmdSQL.Parameters("@FixedDimension").Value = "NEATOL"
                End If
            End With
            con.Open()
            cmdSQL.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using
        ResetControls()
    End Sub
    Private Sub ResetControls()
        Dim lstChkBx As New List(Of CheckBox) From {MissedPartCHKB, MissedAutomatedPartCHKB, NotInEpicorCHKB, NonStockCHKB, MissedSTKItemCHKB, MissedBuyoutCHKB, MissedPrintsNOTSentChadCHKB, MissingPrintAfterQTYCHKB, AddedMissingDimCHKB, FixedDimensionCHKB, OtherCHKB}
        For Each chk As CheckBox In lstChkBx
            chk.Checked = False
        Next
        OtherTXTB.Text = ""
        ' eventually change the month list to automatically select based on the current date
        'If this is a ListBox
        MonthList2021.SelectedIndex = -1
    End Sub
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What's happening here: ".Add("@StockNumber", OleDbType.Date, 100).Value = """

Comment: @AndrewMortimer Well, eventually that text will be autofilled in from an open program, but I don't have that set up yet, so it's blank for the time being.

Comment: I also changed the .date to .varchar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should always store date and time as *DateTime*, not as text or anything else, no exceptions.

Thus, change the data type to DateTime and try:

```
.Add("@TimeLog", OleDbType.Date).Value = DateTime.Now
```

Comment: Do you think it is worth mentioning explicitly that the datatype on the table needs to be changed?

Comment: I think so. The questioneer seems to have changed it from _DateTime_ to _Short Text_; a bad move indeed.

Comment: @gustav thought that was what was causing the error, my bad.